# Adjusting Height of the flex item in Angular depending on the unknown content from an API

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

I have the following code in my angular app.

> template

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="detail">
      <p>{{object.key1}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="detail">
      <p>{{object.key2}} </p>
    </div>
    <div class="detail">
      <p>{{object.key2}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

> scss

```
.container{
        width: 50%;
        border: 2px solid green;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
}
```

The above code nicely arranges the `detail` div inside the `container` div.
But the text inside the `detail` div is going outside.

I can adjust this by giving an `height` and some `padding` to `detail` div, but the number of lines of content is dynamic and unknown and I can not really decide on the height.
Is this because of the unknown amount of content. If so, how can I fit the unknown amount of content(text) that I get from an API inside the flex items.

I could not find any solution online.
Any help would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: Can you share the error image?

Comment: Are you able to see the image link? For some reason, I cant see.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't see